# STM32cube printf to SWD stops working when C++

Tags: stm32cubeide

I had a main.c file with SWV prinf working just fine in the SWV console.   Now I changed the main.c file to cpp file and now print to SWV stops working.

How to fix? Using STM32CubeIDE and gnu tools.

I had added _write() to main function to get printf SWD working working on the c file, now on cpp file _write never gets called?

The only thing I changed is renaming the file to .cpp to invoke the c++ compiler...

more context... will look in map file and _write is in the main.cpp file calling the printf.

Using STM32CubeIDE with eabi compiler and a newcomer to the stm tools.  Have STM32F407 board and created a new c project with the help of STMCubeMX.

i also use an STLink clone modified with to use the SWD's SWO debugging via adding an override for the _write() function in my main.c code as i fouind discussed in many places. Download and Debugging all works fine, and i can get printf() output on the SWO IDM console just fine.... as a .c main file.

now i want to move forward with using a bit of the nicer artifacts of C++ without the baggage.
from what i read, i only had to rename the main.c file to .cpp, and doing this causes the g++ compiler to get invoked. all is well

All was going fine, creating a few simple classes etc, code runs fine, single stepping/download all OK.

HOWEVER - i have lost the printf() SWV/IDM console debugging output... compiling in cpp rather than c breaks it... the call to printf works, but it never makes it to the _write() function that writes it to the ITM_SendChar()

what does it take to regain the printf to SWV console with cpp ??

i'm at a standstill as i may have to revert back to straight C code, as i feel having the printf via IDM console is a
"must have".  as above how to i get back what lost on the SWD/IDM console "printf" ??

NOTE: i created ths little fragment of code

int __io_putchar(int ch) {

ITM_SendChar(ch);

return ch;

}

and called it with a terminated string, and the ITM console output the string... so proving ITM_SendChar() is working fine.

SO.. something is disconnected between printf and how it gets to _write() and thereafter to the ITM_SendChar() in the _write() functin i have in main()..

HOw do i fix this ?? its gotta be something silly/stupid im missing.  PS - tried cout as well (with ), did the same thing as printf... nothing and returns...

help me Obeewan Kenobee

Comment: Does your .map file contain _write?

Comment: Is the _write function in c or cpp file?

Answer (score 3):

FIXED, it was simple.

All I needed to do was to provide the `_write()` I wrote to provide ITM console output with C linkage directive.

```
// used for support of printf out of SWD when using C++
extern "C" {
int _write(int file, char *ptr, int len)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i<len; i++)
            ITM_SendChar((*ptr++));
        return len;
    }
}
```

I should have thought about this before. Name mangling of CPP didn't allow the override of the `_write()` in the syscalls file with my new one which redirected the `printf` to the `ITM_SendChar(ch)` and thereby out to the ITM console output. The linker didn't find the override because there wasn't one!